# Array Out of Bounds lendo Arquivo

Tags: java, array

Estou tendo um problema com o meu código, em meu arquivo de texto que devo ler a última linha é em branco, e então ela não deve ser lida, porem estou recebendo *out of bounds*.

Linha para exemplo do arquivo:

> Fernando&60.9&166

Classe main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList< Paciente > listaPacientes = new ArrayList< Paciente >(); 
        Paciente p = new Paciente();

        String filename = "F:\\NetBeansProjects\\IMC.txt";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = in.readLine();
            line = in.readLine();
            line = in.readLine();
            int a =4;
            while (line != null) {
                if(!line.startsWith(" ")){
                String result[] = line.split("&");
                listaPacientes.add(new Paciente(result[0], Double.parseDouble(result[1]), Integer.parseInt(result[2])));
                }
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo \"" + filename + "\" não existe.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro na leitura do arquivo " + filename + ".");
        }
```

Comment: Verifique o conteúdo de `result` no *debugger*, especialmente o `size()` (talvez colocando um *watchpoint* quando ele for menor que 3). Pode ser que os dados não estejam no formato que você deseja. O que aliás mostra uma fraqueza do algoritmo. Sempre é possível vir algo não esperado.

Comment: Sem consertar as fragilidades que o @bigown apontou, você poderia ainda verificar se a linha `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 2):

Se o objetivo é não ler a última linha em branco, a instrução seguinte pode te gerar esta exceção:

```
listaPacientes.add(new Paciente(result[0], Double.parseDouble(result[1]), Integer.parseInt(result[2])));
```

Porque a condição de leitura do ciclo, `line != null`, verifica apenas se não houver mais linhas e se o "linha em branco" a que te referes for um texto vazio `""`, então este erro vai mesmo ocorrer.

Sugiro a o seguinte no ciclo:

```
while (line != null) {
   if(!line.trim().isEmpty()){
        ...
   }
   line = in.readLine();
}
```

A exceção é `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` normalmente ocorre quando acedes à uma posição inválida. Verifique bem as posições que acedes quando adicionas novos pacientes.